# How to deploy spark job to EMR yarn cluster from Jenkins?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I have several spark jobs on a EMR cluster using yarn that must run on a regular basis and are submitted from Jenkins. Currently the Jenkins machine will ssh into the master node on EMR where a copy of the code is ready in a folder to be executed. I would like to be able to clone my repo into the jenkins workspace and submit the code from Jenkins to be executed on the cluster. Is there a simple way to do this? What is the best way to deploy spark from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [rest api](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) to call http requests from Jenkins to Start/Stop the jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python in Jenkins, implement script using [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good, easy, flexible and powerful option.

You can manage EMR (So Spark) creating the full cluster or adding jobs to an existing one.
Also, using the same library, you can manage all AWS services.